# During deploying Django blog on heroku showes me errors

Tags: django, heroku, pip, python-3.7, heroku-cli

When I deploy app in heroku show me this error

```
remote: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_16067d5dbf345d8d906970e4d4f44d30/requirements.txt
```

I searched on internet to finding the  solution of that problem but can't successfully find this.

So I show you what steps I had do for deploy app in heroku
I typed in terminal

```
heroku login    
pip3 freeze
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then for instaling gunicorn type in terminal

```
pip3 install gunicorn
```

Then make a file in root directory write name is Procifle in which I write

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi
```

Then my heroku blog name

```
heroku git:remote -a naqviblog
```

I also show you my requirements.txt file

```
apturl==0.5.2
asgiref==3.2.3
asn1crypto==0.24.0
blinker==1.4
boto3==1.9.96
botocore==1.12.96
Brlapi==0.6.7
certifi==2018.8.24
chardet==3.0.4
command-not-found==0.3
cryptography==2.3
cupshelpers==1.0
defer==1.0.6
distro==1.3.0
distro-info===0.21ubuntu2
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.4
django-crispy-forms==1.9.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-storages==1.7.1
docutils==0.14
entrypoints==0.3
f.lux-indicator-applet==1.1.11rc0
galternatives==1.0.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
httplib2==0.11.3
idna==2.6
jmespath==0.9.3
keyring==17.1.1
keyrings.alt==3.1.1
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.6
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.2
lazr.uri==1.0.3
lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings==1.2.2
louis==3.8.0
macaroonbakery==1.2.1
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
netifaces==0.10.4
oauth==1.0.1
oauthlib==2.1.0
olefile==0.46
pbr==5.4.4
pexpect==4.6.0
Pillow==5.4.1
protobuf==3.6.1
psycopg2==2.7.7
pycairo==1.16.2
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.73
PyGObject==3.32.0
PyJWT==1.7.0
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pyRFC3339==1.1
python-apt===1.8.5-ubuntu0.3
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-debian==0.1.34
python-decouple==3.3
pytz==2018.9
pyxattr==0.6.1
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.13
reportlab==3.5.18
requests==2.21.0
requests-unixsocket==0.1.5
s3transfer==0.2.0
SecretStorage==2.3.1
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
system-service==0.3
systemd-python==234
testresources==2.0.1
ubuntu-advantage-tools==19.2
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
ufw==0.36
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.24.1
usb-creator==0.3.3
virtualenv==15.1.0
wadllib==1.3.3
whitenoise==4.1.2
xkit==0.0.0
youtube-dl==2019.1.17
zope.interface==4.3.2
```

Then type in terminal

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit changes"
```

finally type

```
git push heroku master
```

then showed me this error

```
Enumerating objects: 77, done.
Counting objects: 100% (77/77), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
Writing objects: 100% (67/67), 3.72 MiB | 421.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 67 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Clearing cached dependencies
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.10
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: Sqlite3 successfully installed.
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_d533b9574fcab74e6906cdc8732269b2/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for apturl==0.5.2 (from -r /tmp/build_d533b9574fcab74e6906cdc8732269b2/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to naqviblog.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/naqviblog.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/naqviblog.git'
```

when open this link `https://git.heroku.com/naqviblog.git`
then show me on browser

```
Method Not Allowed
```

Answer (score 1):

- That's a lot of packages. Are you sure your project requires them all?
- You added the python-3.7 tag but Heroku says it is using python 3.6. Ensure that both developing and production environment match.
- `apturl` does not exist on PyPI https://pypi.org/. When you run `python -m pip install packagename` you search for it on PyPI. It does not exist on there. You may have installed it through `apt`, `setup.py`, `wheels`, etc.

Comment: Oh but I'm using python 3.7 now it's not working?
No Idea but it's automatically generated when type heroku freeze  
how i install it using setup.py or apt?

Comment: I have no idea where you got that package from. I cannot tell you how to install it. You should use Python's virtual environment and only install packages that are necessary for your program to run and then generate a requirements.txt from that.